# Can't set values for select option in Contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add a option value for select dropdown in CF7. I am using following shortcode to generate HTML like

```
<select name="Construction" class="form-control">
    <option value="opt1">Masonry</option>
    <option value="opt2">Frame</option>
    <option value="opt3">Mixed Masonry-Frame</option>
</select>
```

My Shortcode is:

```
[select* Construction class:form-control "Masonry|opt1" "Frame|opt2" "Mixed Masonry-Frame|opt3"]
```

But All I got is:

```
<select name="Construction" class="form-control">
    <option value="Masonry">Masonry</option>
    <option value="Frame">Frame</option>
    <option value="Mixed Masonry-Frame">Mixed Masonry-Frame</option>
</select>
```

I just followed the patterns used in https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Note : WPCF7_USE_PIPE was set true.

Comment: try with line break

Comment: There isn't any perfect solution from Plugin developer too.. but one developer has fixed by own using jquery. Try if you want to : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-pipes-not-working-3/

Comment: Another important comment in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70994/35182)

Comment: @Mikethetechy I already tried that one. its not helping

Comment: @ShaunakShukla I read that earlier. I followed that CF7 documentation but it does not fix my issue.

Comment: In comment it is mentioned-"This will work server side only. According to the documentation this is to prevent values to be sent to the browser client" and on in documentation "To get the value after pipe character, put the usual mail tag corresponding to the form tag ([your-recipient] in the case of the above example) in the Mail templates. To get value before pipe, you can use [_raw_{field name}] ([_raw_your-recipient] in the case of the above example)."

Answer (score 8):

You might not need it anymore, but I came across the same problem today.

I solved it by filtering **wpcf7_form_tag**.

In my opinion a better solution than using JS because the values will be changed server-side before any form HTML is rendered.

Example implementation which should make the pipes work the way you want:

```
function so48515097_cf7_select_values($tag)
{
    if ($tag['basetype'] != 'select') {
        return $tag;
    }

    $values = [];
    $labels = [];
    foreach ($tag['raw_values'] as $raw_value) {
        $raw_value_parts = explode('|', $raw_value);
        if (count($raw_value_parts) >= 2) {
            $values[] = $raw_value_parts[1];
            $labels[] = $raw_value_parts[0];
        } else {
            $values[] = $raw_value;
            $labels[] = $raw_value;
        }
    }
    $tag['values'] = $values;
    $tag['labels'] = $labels;

    // Optional but recommended:
    //    Display labels in mails instead of values
    //    You can still use values using [_raw_tag] instead of [tag]
    $reversed_raw_values = array_map(function ($raw_value) {
        $raw_value_parts = explode('|', $raw_value);
        return implode('|', array_reverse($raw_value_parts));
    }, $tag['raw_values']);
    $tag['pipes'] = new \WPCF7_Pipes($reversed_raw_values);

    return $tag;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag', 'so48515097_cf7_select_values', 10);
```

Edit:

In the backend, the *[tag]* will be replaced by the **value, not the label**. But if you still want to have the label displayed in the e-mails instead, then that is also possible by recreating (reversing) the CF7 pipes. That way, you can actually choose which one to use. *[tag]* will display the label and *[_raw_tag]* will display the value.

I have edited the code above to reflect this. It is optional of course.

Comment: Should it perhaps be `if (count($raw_value_parts) >= 2) {` in line 11 instead? Thanks for this, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Yes, it needs to be like that! Not sure how I missed that when posting here. I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work server side only. According to the documentation this is to prevent values to be sent to the browser client.

I found this comment by [Herbert Van-Vliet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/106338/herbert-van-vliet) on this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70994)

So, On submit you will get exact value which you have defined through Pipe Operator ("|")